# How to get CSS value from JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm doing responsive design and using @Media to set up CSS depending on the size of the screen.  I set up a css value called

.dskcell { display: none; }

and set it to none if the media is small otherwise display: normal.  What I want to know how to get the display value of dskcell in pure Javascript?

I see getComputedStyle but that seems like it needs a HTML element which on some pages the css isn't used.  How can I find out what display value of dskcell is in JS ?

EDIT:

```
<ul id="mnu" class="page dskcell">
```

In Javascript, i need to know if its being hidden or shown so am hopping to see what the display value of dskcell is.

Comment: It’s not that “the value of the class is something”. Those values get applied *to elements* based on selectors and media queries. You can only meaningfully evaluate them on a specific element. To know the size of the screen in Javascript you don’t need CSS at all; just check the appropriate Javascript property.

Comment: maybe if you share enough code demonstrating your issue, you could get efficient help and it could  explain why getComputedStyle is not working for you. unless you did not use it properly. if no `.dskcell` then you should not get any value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: try: document.querySelector('#mnu').style.display; OR document.getElementById('mnu').style.display; You call select the classes also with querySelector just swap the '#' to '.' .

Comment: from my previous comment: here is what i mean : https://jsfiddle.net/umokv29d/ and https://jsfiddle.net/umokv29d/1/ You need to check if default display is reset or not. If it is set/reset, then you have a value that you can use. if not, default value is applied (ul is a block, span is inline, li is list-item, etc... )

Comment: So what is it you *really* want to do? Figure out whether the element is displayed or not? And based on that you want to do what?

Comment: What I really wanted to do was if the .dskcell was none then not populate a menu, populate another menu instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to check, with pure javascript, whether the dskcell element is displayed. If the media query applies (or there is no dskcell element), `dskcellIsDisplayed` will be false (otherwise it will be true).

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const elem = document.querySelector('.dskcell');
  const dskcellIsDisplayed = elem && window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("display") !== 'none';
  console.log(dskcellIsDisplayed);
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .dskcell {
    display: none;
  }
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dskcell"></div>
```

Comment: @MiscellaneousUser Based on your question, you should have been already aware of this method…‽

Comment: I was aware of the getComputedStyle but I couldn't get it to work.  I was trying to look at the css rather than elements which is why I discounted the command.  In the end, I took a different approach and used this method instead.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why would you need the value when you just want to change it... then normally it wouldn't matter what was the value before.

```js
if (window.innerWidth > 1200 ) {
    const el = document.querySelector('.el');
    el.style.display = 'none';
} else {
    el.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Or with computed:
You say not all elements have the class name '.dskcell' Well, add another class to all of them?

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.element')
const style = getComputedStyle(element).display
console.log(style) // expected: block / none
```

If you really need the value...
As the last thing on the list since you know the initial value you set in css, you could create an object that holds data of your component as you just want to toggle between block & none you know all possible values...